# Textures always show up in pink

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am really new to Blender, and by the title I mean that when importing/creating a new texture, blender always says that there are missing textures, I have succeeded in painting/importing textures on this same file before, but now it's not working anymore. I have tried the report and find missing files feature, but that does nothing. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: pink, regardless of the presence of any textures]

Comment: Are the textures in the same place as your model? Have you tried going into 'Material Properties' manually creating a new texture, opening your texture and then applying it to the model? If that doesn't work then maybe go into 'Edit Mode' select all the faces and choose 'assign' in the Material Properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object and go to the shader editor, add an image texture by pressing shift>A and then connect the image texture node into the base color. In the image texture node press open and select your file or just open the dropdown menu and select the file from there. Now go to the texture paint workspace and check. It will not be pink.

Comment: thanks! it works like a charm