# Missing Textures That Don't Exists At All

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders

I bought these models and I'm trying to texture paint them. However, I'm getting "Missing Textures Detected" error anytime I try painting them. There wasn't any other files attached to the OBJ that came with the download (Like the the MTL) so I can't do External Data> Find Missing Files. Are there any other work around? Like can I create new texture files for the model? If so, how can I do so?

Thank you all in advance!

Danny

Comment: Does this help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215243/textures-always-show-up-in-pink/215244#215244

Comment: That definitely helped! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're Welcome (!